# Load Oracle .dmp files into Hive

Tags: oracle, hive

I'd like to use Oracle .dmp files as a source for Hive tables.
I have found SerDe that could be used: oracle.hadoop.hive.datapump.DPSerDe
Is it availiable for free? Where can I download it from?

There is almost no information about it... [(https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/External-Hive-table-for-the-oracle-dmp-file/td-p/59874)](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/External-Hive-table-for-the-oracle-dmp-file/td-p/59874)

Comment: [`oracle.hadoop.hive.datapump.DPSerDe`](https://blogs.oracle.com/bigdataconnectors/how-to-load-oracle-and-hive-tables-using-ohsh-part-4-loading-hive-tables)is part of Oracle's Big Data Connector capability which they wrote for their Big Data Appliance (hardware/software). BDA is Oracle's audacious plan to muscle in on the Big Data market by selling expensive engineered hardware with free (open source) software pre-installed, plus some nifty Oracle connectors to integrate Hadoop with Oracle. The main point of those connectors was to sell BDAs, so it seems unlikely we can just download them.

Comment: No, actually you can download the BDA virtual machine. This sandbox machine contains a hadoop distribution and oracle database.